# Problem output angular table html entities

Tags: html, angular, output, html-entities, angular-sortablejs

I have an Text in my DB. Output like {{ roll.Text }}
The Problem is, have an output with html-entities.. if I have `<h2>Text</h2>` in my html I need **Text**.

My Code:

```
      <script>
            angular.module('sortApp', [])
            .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
                $scope.sortType = 'name'; // set the default sort type
                $scope.sortReverse = false;  // set the default sort order
                $scope.searchFish = '';     // set the default search/filter term

                // create the list of edit rolls
                $scope.edit = [
                    <?php
                    while($row_post = $result_post->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $plant_id = $row_post['plant_id'];
                        $titel= $row_post['name'];
                        $text = $row_post['beschreibung'];
                        $datum = $row_post['datum'];
                        $del = $row_post['del'];
                        $uid = $_SESSION['id'];
                    ?>

                    {ID: '<?php echo $plant_id ?>', Titel: '<?php echo $titel; ?>', Text: '<?php echo $text; ?>', Datum: '<?php echo date("j.m.Y", $datum) ?>',
                     Del: '<?php echo $del; ?>', UID: '<?php echo $uid ?>'},

                    <?php } ?>
                ];

            });
    </script>
```

```
<textarea class="uk-textarea"  rows="5" name="beschreibung" id="editor"  style="min-height: 150px;" required>{{ roll.Text }}</textarea>
```

Comment: You may need to read this one first [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why are you still using AngularJS? the project is being discontinued by google in `July 2021`, move on to Angular 2+

Comment: Sorry - First: My Englisch is verry Bad...

Comment: Thanks. Angular 2+ Examples?